# Classify strings having centers already found, python

Tags: python, classification, cluster-analysis, text-classification

I have a list of binary strings and two center strings which are not in the list.
I would like to classify that list around the center strings in order to create two clusters. A string of the list will be assigned to the cluster whose center is nearest to that string (hamming distance as metric).
I've seen that there are alghoritms like Neighbours Classifier, k-medoids, Affinity propagation, but all these procedure calculate centroids on their own; I have to use my center strings instead.

Any suggestion?

Comment: This is probably better suited for [stats.se], but you could just store your strings in a [space-partitioning data-structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_partitioning#Data_structures) like a kd-tree

Comment: @juanpaarrivillaga no it is not suited for CV - it is a programming question, and please do *not* suggest posting duplicates, but only to migrate questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perform 1-nearest neighbor classification using your *centers* only.

No need for anything special here. Just assign to the nearest center.